# Getting legends with dashed line in ggplot when errorbars are solid

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm having difficulty with getting the legend to behave as I want it when I do a ggplot with errorbars. As the errorbars look ridiculous with a dashed line I force it to a solid one, unfortunately this also results in that the legend forgets about the dashed property.

There are several similar SO-questions but I haven't found any that truly address this particular problem ([this one is probably the closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077274/ggplot2-manually-specifying-color-linetype-duplicate-legend), [another similar can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/creating-a-ggplot-legend-with-both-color-and-shape)). Hadley did gave an answer 2010 on a very [similar question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/ggplot2-s-geom-errorbar-legend-td2122042.html) on the R-help list but I'm not sure how to implement it, also it seems like a lot of work as I have four lines and two facets in my actual plot.

**Test code**

```
set.seed(1)
test_df <- data.frame(models = rep(paste("Model", LETTERS[1:3]), 3),
                      x = c(rep(1, 3),
                            rep(2, 3),
                            rep(3, 3)),
                      y = c(1:3,1:3+1+rnorm(3,0,.2),1:3+2)+rnorm(3,0,.3))
test_df$ymax <- test_df$y + .3
test_df$ymin <- test_df$y - .3

ggplot(test_df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=models, linetype=models)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin), linetype=1, 
                lwd=1.2, width=.5)
```

[image: The plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ha, just as I had given up and was about to post my question I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873647/removing-a-layer-legend-in-ggplot) - it turns out that `guide="none"` or `guide=FALSE` that I had tried is not the correct option, the key is in the `show_guide` option:

```
ggplot(test_df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=models, linetype=models)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin), linetype=1, 
                lwd=1.2, width=.5, show_guide=FALSE)
```

[image: Dashed legend]

Comment: `guide="none"` would be an argument to `scale_linetype`, not the geom, and would completely suppress the guide for linetype (all lines in the legend would be solid); `show_guide=FALSE` in the geom instead indicates that that particular geom should not contribute to determining what is shown in the legend.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Thanks, I find the ggplot help a little confusing at times, for instance there is no mentioning of show_guide as an option in either the main help or the layer page that ... refers to.

Comment: True. It does show up in some examples, and in the geoms where it is not true by default, but it is not properly documented.